# Creating a simple "Logged In As" line on my page

Tags: php, authentication, echo

```
   <?php 
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['login']))
{

 include_once('includes/header.php'); ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <div id="mainframe">
        <img src="img/header.png">
        <div id="menu">
            <?php include_once('includes/navbar.php'); ?>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <h3>Shopping Cart</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php include_once('includes/footer.php'); ?>
</body>
</html>
<?php }
    else
    {
    header('location: login.php');
    }
?>
```

Here is my small PhP code I've got at the moment, my login session is $_SESSION['login'].
And I'd like to display : Logged in As on my page when they are logged in, I've tried several things but it didn't work out.
Does anyone know a simple method / solution for this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

U need to pass **username** using SESSION variable for the same

write a simple sql query to get the username from any variable you are taking from user to make sure that the particular user is the correct user.i am taking password.

```
   $query = "SELECT name FROM users WHERE password='$password'";
   $username = mysql_result(mysql_query($query),0);

   $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
```

than proceed as you are doing

```
<?php 
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['login']) && isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
echo "logged in as".$_SESSION['username'];
}
```

Comment: Hm, my login session wont start once the && isset($_SESSION['username'])) is there and the $login isn't a defined variable.

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: login in C:\wamp\www\ProjectV1.45\cart.php on line 2
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0003 251464 {main}( ) ..\cart.php:0

( ! ) Warning: mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\ProjectV1.45\cart.php on line 3

Comment: first tell me how you are validating user?means in the table is username present.whoever will login in your system u will validate password right so along with password fetch username also

Comment: you are getting the error because your query is not executing u need to get the $logid value from the user than use this in query

Comment: @user3074608 you can mark my answer as answered if it was correct as per your question

Answer (score 2):

Put this somewhere in your if statement.
It will show *Logged in as User* at right top corner of page

```
<div style="position:absolute; right:0px; top:0px;">
<?php echo "Logged In as". $_SESSION['login']; ?>
</div>
```